# How is the cash flow perpetuity formula derived?

Tags: cash-flow

I don't know if this is the correct StackExchange community (it seems more related to personal finance than corporate finance), but I would greatly appreciate if someone could clarify to me this formula I found reading the excellent book "Valuation" by McKinsey and Company. At page 50 the cash flow perpetuity formula is presented:

[image: Formula showing Value = (F C F_t=1) / ( W ACC - g)]

and it's stated that for the derivation, the reader should see T. E. Copeland and J. Fred Weston, *Financial Theory and Corporate Policy*, 3rd ed., Appendix A. As I'm currently in a remote location in the countryside, I'm unable to gain access to this book through a library. Does someone know how the formula is derived?
Thank you so much!

Comment: This formula is similar to the dividend discount model. Refer to the dividend discount model's derivation on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividend_discount_model#Derivation_of_equation

Comment: Thank you so much Flux!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user Flux to help me find the answer.
This formula is derived simply applying the limit for n -> ∞ to the present value of a sum from 1 to n of annuities with growing payments, for example when modeling the growing dividends payed out by a firm, assuming the rate of growth g is constant